# How to scroll in the webview Android device using Appium to find the matching text?

Tags: android, scroll, appium

As the swipe methods are deprecated from version 5.0 onwards in the latest Appium client library. Could someone pl provide solutions.

The below piece of code is working partially.

```
  Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();
  Double screenHeightStart = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5;
  int scrollStart = screenHeightStart.intValue();
  Double screenHeightEnd = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2;
  int scrollEnd = screenHeightEnd.intValue();
  new TouchAction(driver).press(0, scrollStart).waitAction(2000)
  .moveTo(0, scrollEnd).release().perform();
```